# how to call column which has space in column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I would like to know how do i call the column name which has space ? My example code is below as you can see **FIRST NAME** is seperated by space.

```
hr.loc[((hr.FIRST NAME == 'TOMASA') & (hr.UNIT == 'Finance')), ["DESIGNATION","UNIT"]]
```

**Result:**

[image]

Regards,

Bharath Vikas

Comment: Use - `hr["FIRST NAME"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to: `hr['FIRST NAME']`.

You can use "attribute notation" (e.g. *hr.UNIT*) as long as the column name
is a valid identifier (names with spaces aren't).